# How do I update data in indexedDB?

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I have tried to get some information from [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) regarding the update of an objectStore item in a indexedDB database, but with not so much susccess.
I found [here](http://dominoc925.blogspot.ro/2012/06/use-html5-indexeddb-cursors-to-update.html) a way to do it, but it doesn't really work for me.

My implementation is something like this

```
DBM.activitati.edit = function(id, obj, callback){
    var transaction = DBM.db.transaction(["activitati"], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("activitati");
    var keyRange = IDBKeyRange.only(id);

    objCursor = objectStore.openCursor(keyRange);
    objCursor.onsuccess = function(e){
        var cursor = e.target.result;
        console.log(obj);
        var request = cursor.update(obj);
        request.onsuccess = function(){
            callback();
        }
        request.onerror = function(e){
            conosole.log("DBM.activitati.edit -> error " + e);
        }

    }   
    objCursor.onerror = function(e){
        conosole.log("DBM.activitati.edit -> error " + e);
    }                   
}
```

I have all DBM.activitati.(add | remove | getAll | getById | getByIndex) methods working, but I can not resolve this.

If you know how I can manage it, please, do tell!

Thank you!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taylorbuley/TLTfn/) for some examples on how to update IDB records. I worked on that with another StackOverflower -- it's a pretty decent standalone example of IndexedDB that uses indexes and does updates.

The method you seem to be looking for is [`put`](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBObjectStore-put-IDBRequest-any-value-any-key), which will either insert or update a record if there are unique indexes. In that example fiddle, it's used like this:

```
    phodaDB.indexedDB.addUser = function(userObject){
        //console.log('adding entry: '+entryTxt);
        var db = phodaDB.indexedDB.db;
        var trans = db.transaction(["userData"],IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
        var store = trans.objectStore("userData");
        var request = store.put(userObject);

        request.onsuccess = function(e){
            phodaDB.indexedDB.getAllEntries();
        };
        request.onerror = function(e){
            console.log('Error adding: '+e);
        };
    };
```

For what it's worth, you've got some possible syntax errors, misspelling "console" in `console.log` as "conosole".

Comment: Thank you! This indexedDB looks increasingly better! I thought it doesn't know to handle this so easy..

Comment: IDB is amazing. Ask away if you run into problems but also search SO for answers on stuff. I try not to let any question go unanswered.

Comment: Clear to understand and easy to implement, +1

Comment: @buley How can I append a value to an array field in IDB?

Comment: I do not know but put() function is not working for me it creates new entry but it does not update the given item. I even tried with key/

Do you know the reason why put() is not working??

Instead i used cursor.update() it worked.

Answer (score 6):

A bit late for an answer, but possible it helps others. I still stumbled -as i guess- over the same problem, but it's very simple:

If you want to INSERT or UPDATE records you use `objectStore.put(object)` [(help)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/put)
If you only want to INSERT records you use `objectStore.add(object)` [(help)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/add)

So if you use `add(object)`, and a record key still exists in DB, it will not overwritten and fires error 0 "ConstraintError: Key already exists in the object store".
If you use `put(object)`, it will be overwritten.

Answer (score 3):

this is case of update infos of an user object

```
var transaction = db.transaction(["tab_user"], "readwrite");
var store = transaction.objectStore("tab_user");

var req = store.openCursor();
req.onerror = function(event) {
  console.log("case if have an error");
};

req.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if(cursor){
        if(cursor.value.idUser == users.idUser){//we find by id an user we want to update
            var user = {};
            user.idUser = users.idUser ;
            user.nom = users.nom ;

            var res = cursor.update(user);
            res.onsuccess = function(e){
                console.log("update success!!");
            }
            res.onerror = function(e){
                console.log("update failed!!");
            }
        }
        cursor.continue();
    }
    else{
        console.log("fin mise a jour");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for drawing attention to cursor.update().
MDN: "Returns an IDBRequest object, and, in a separate thread, updates the value at the current position of the cursor in the object store. This can be used to update specific records."

Answer (score 3):

I'm a couple of years late, but thought it'd be nice to add my two cents in.

First, check out [BakedGoods](https://github.com/klawson88/Baked-Goods) if you don't want to deal with the complex IndexedDB API.

It's a library which establishes a uniform interface that can be used to conduct storage operations in all native, and some non-native client storage facilities. It also maintains the flexibility and options afforded to the user by each. Oh, and it's maintained by yours truly :) .

With it, placing one or more data items in an object store can be as simple as:

```
bakedGoods.set({
    data: [{key: "key1", value: "value1"}, {key: "key2", value: "value2"}),
    storageTypes: ["indexedDB"],
    complete: function(byStorageTypeResultDataObj, byStorageTypeErrorObj){}
});
```

---

Now to answer the actual question...

Lets begin by aggregating the valuable information spread across the existing answers:

- `IDBObjectStore.put()` adds a new record to the store, or updates an existing one
- `IDBObjectStore.add()` adds a new record to the store
- `IDBCursor.update()` updates the record at the current position of the cursor

As one can see, OP is using an appropriate method to update a record. There are, however, several things in his/her code, unrelated to the method, that are incorrect (with respect to the API today at least). I've identified and corrected them below:

```
var cursorRequest = objectStore.openCursor(keyRange); //Correctly define result as request

cursorRequest.onsuccess = function(e){                //Correctly set onsuccess for request
    var objCursor = cursorRequest.result;             //Get cursor from request
    var obj = objCursor.value;                        //Get value from existing cursor ref
    console.log(obj);
    var request = objCursor.update(obj);             
    request.onsuccess = function(){
        callback();
    }
    request.onerror = function(e){
        console.log("DBM.activitati.edit -> error " + e); //Use "console" to log :)
    }

}   
cursorRequest.onerror = function(e){                  //Correctly set onerror for request
    console.log("DBM.activitati.edit -> error " + e); //Use "console" to log :)
}
```